# PyQt, Any way to use one changeValue method for multiple sliders?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, slider

I need to have 3 sliders (or more). So at the moment, I have three different changeValues methods for each slider.

In initUI(self), I have three sliders:

```
    sigmaTitle = QtGui.QLabel('Sigma')
    sigmaSlider = QtGui.QSlider(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, self)
    sigmaSlider.setRange(0, 100)
    sigmaSlider.valueChanged[int].connect(self.sigmaChangeValue)

    dtTitle = QtGui.QLabel('Sigma')
    dtSlider = QtGui.QSlider(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, self)
    dtSlider.setRange(200, 400)
    dtSlider.valueChanged[int].connect(self.dtChangeValue)

    rTitle = QtGui.QLabel('Sigma')
    rSlider = QtGui.QSlider(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, self)
    rSlider.setRange(300, 400)
    rSlider.valueChanged[int].connect(self.rChangeValue)
```

Then I have three changeValue methods:

```
def sigmaChangeValue(self, value):
    self.sigma = value / 1000.0
    print self.sigma

def dtChangeValue(self, value):
    self.dt = value / 1000.0
    print self.dt

def rChangeValue(self, value):
    self.r = value / 1000.0
    print self.r
```

so is there a way to use one share changeValue method and still allow to individually assign variable with different range?

Thanks

Comment: Get rid of all the signals and variables, and just read the values directly from the sliders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can connect all slider `valueChanged` signals to the same slot.
If you need to know which slider has sent the signal, you can use the `QObject.sender()` method inside the slot.
See [QObject.sender()](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qobject.html#sender)

Example:

```
#create the sliders using self:
self.sigmaSlider = QtGui.QSlider(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, self)
self.sigmaSlider.setRange(0, 100)
#etc...
```

The slot:

```
def mySlot(self, value):
    if self.sender() == self.sigmaSlider:
        self.sigma = value / 1000.0
        print self.sigma
    elif self.sender() == self.dtSlider:
        #etc....
```

Comment: If all slots do the same thing there is not even a need to identify its sender. But otherwise your answer would also be my suggestion.

Comment: Thanks. I think this what i need. quick additional question. In that case, can I mix both sliders and other widget e.g. QLineEdit together in one box?

Comment: If I understand right, yes. You can put many widget of different types inside another widget as childred and/or put many different widgets inside the same layout

Comment: I managed to put sliders and spinBox together. But I need to create a separate method for lineEdit. Because in slider and spinBox the method is def changeValue(self, value). It complains about taking too many arguments. So I made a separate method def textChangedValue(self):